# how to override timestamp field coming from json in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, filebeat, metricbeat

I have the following below kind of json present with me to be dumped in elastic search  using filebeat `{"@timestamp":"2017-02-10T06:30:51.424Z","beat":{"hostname":"myhostname","name":"mydevice-logger","version":"5.2.0"},"fields":{"device_type":"mydevice","env":"staging"},"metricset":{"module":"system","name":"cpu","rtt":211},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":4,"idle":{"pct":0.000000},"iowait":{"pct":0.000000},"irq":{"pct":0.000000},"nice":{"pct":0.000000},"softirq":{"pct":0.000000},"steal":{"pct":0.000000},"system":{"pct":0.000000},"user":{"pct":0.000000}}},"tags":["automata","box"],"type":"metricbeat-test-log"}`

my logstash( version 5.1.1) config contains, input, filter and output like below -

```
input { 
  beats {
        port => 5046
        codec => json
  }
}

filter {
    if ...{}
    else if [type] == "metricbeat-test-log" {

      date {
        match => ["@timestamp", "ISO8601"]
      }

      }
    }

}


output {
    if ...{}
    else if [type] == "metricbeat-test-log" {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug   }
    }
}
```

The type is right however the date filter is not working . The `@timestamp` finally takes current timestamp always . I want to replace it with original `@timestamp` present in json.

Comment: Are you really using Filebeat to write Metricbeat's JSON data to Elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes the reason is its an offline device. I collect metricbeat log and putting them in to elastic search

Comment: though I can simply use a python script to dump the whole json into ES however I find using filebeat more practical for my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer following this old thread https://discuss.elastic.co/t/replace-timestamp-with-actual-timestamp-from-log-file/72017 which explains that the `"@timestamp":"2017-02-10T06:30:51.424Z"` in log line above is a JSON representation of the @timestamp field and its value. Following the suggestions I added the json configuration in filebeat and it worked for me .

```
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /var/logs/mylogs/*.log
  fields:
    environment: testing
  document_type: test-metric-document

  json.keys_under_root: true   # added this line 
  json.overwrite_keys: true    # added this line
```

Though I am not happy with this solution as my real need was to get the both timestamp, the logstash event one(in some other variable ) and the timestamp from log in @timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the target setting in the date filter :

From https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.1/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-target

**Target**

Value type is string

Default value is "@timestamp"

Store the matching timestamp into the given target field. If not provided, default to updating the @timestamp field of the event.

Comment: bren , I also thought same and had tried it , it gives `_dateparsefailure` because it can not find the @timestamp field . @timestamp in logs is not usually a string but instead an object . More details discussed in https://discuss.elastic.co/t/replace-timestamp-with-actual-timestamp-from-log-file/72017